# Change first row of GridView - Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

How can I change the first row of GridView? My GridView have 2 columns, I want first row to have one column and custom layout which I will inflate in. Can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can customize this. Create an xml such that first you have an ImageVIew and followed by GridView. If you have more such imbalances in GridView, you can use StaggeredGridView.

Comment: But I want the first row (Custom xml) to scroll down with grid view

Answer (score 0):

The following Code works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photo_contest_view_pager_previous_contest_page_photo_imageView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/photo_contest_view_pager_previous_contest_page_image_gridView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
            </GridView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you test it? I cannot scroll down at all :/

Comment: The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (GridView)

Comment: Checked again. Its working for me luckily. Actually I agree A grid view doesn't work in Scroll View, But try the Same Code containing Linear Layout Parent and with-in that scroll view with an image and another GridView.

Comment: This is bad solution cause all elements of GridView always in device memory.